# @EnableJpaRepositories.enableDefaultTransactions = false not working

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The JavaDoc reads

> Configures whether to enable default transactions for Spring Data JPA repositories. Defaults to true. If disabled, repositories must be used behind a facade that's configuring transactions (e.g. using Spring's annotation driven transaction facilities) or repository methods have to be used to demarcate transactions.

I debugged into the framework, and there it just creates a transaction if none exists, even with enableDefaultTransactions = false.

As far as I can see, Spring Data JPA Repositories are pre-configured with @Transactional(readOnly=true) (see SimpleJpaRepository), which leads to nobody noticing when a programmer forgot to properly annotate his service or job with the proper @Transactional because Spring Data JPA creates a transaction for every repository method that's called.

I wanted to disable it. First try was putting a @Transactional(MANDATORY) on my repository super interface. That wasn't working.

Then I noticed "enableDefaultTransactions" in the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation. I set it to false, but nothing changed. The JavaDoc lead me to believe that it would do exactly what I wanted: to remove the default transaction support and throw an exception when using a repository without already being in a transaction context.

Am I wrong? Is this a bug? Is enableDefaultTransactions intended any other way?

Using spring data jpa 1.9.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

The intention of enableDataTransactions=false is to remove the default transaction management from the implementation (I guess from SimpleJpaRepository). It will behave as if no @Transactional was specified. Then you can control transactions in the service layer.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-685

However, regardless of the enableDataTransactions parameter, if you add your own @Transactional annotation in your repository interfaces, it will be correctly applied.

However, however! If you specify @Transactional on the type level, the Spring framework itself (unrelated to data and JPA projects) will apply it only to methods declared in that type, not to the inherited methods. I find this behavior to be correct! Only by overriding the method, you can change its specification and implementation.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<Something, Long> {
    @Override
    public Something findOne(Long id);
}
```

In this sample, MANDATORY propagation will apply to findOne, but it won't to findAll.

Note: Even though I find this behavior correct, I still don't like that there is no standard way to configure the MANDATORY propagation globally. In my opinion, it should even be default.

There were bugs with this in previous releases. I used Spring 4.2.2 and Sprint Data 1.11.0 to test it.

Bug reports:

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-715

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dragan. Meanwhile I added @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY) to all my repositories because enableDataTransactions=false wasn't removing the transaction support in my tests.
I found that the inherited methods weren't used much, if at all, in a real project, so we mostly rely on our own repository methods, which get treated by the mandatory annotation.